# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space and HashMap

Tags: java, recursion, hashmap, out-of-memory

Sorry to post this code again. Previously the issue was I got a stack overflow error which was fixed by using long instead of int. However for a big value of n, I got a Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space.
Question:

```
Given a positive integer n, prints out the sum of the lengths of the Syracuse 
sequence starting in the range of 1 to n inclusive. So, for example, the call:
lengths(3)
will return the the combined length of the sequences:
1
2 1
3 10 5 16 8 4 2 1 
which is the value: 11. lengths must throw an IllegalArgumentException if 
its input value is less than one.
```

My Code:

```
  import java.util.*;


  public class Test {

HashMap<Long,Integer> syraSumHashTable = new HashMap<Long,Integer>();

public Test(){

}

public int lengths(long n)throws IllegalArgumentException{

    int sum =0;

    if(n < 1){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error!! Invalid Input!");
    }   

    else{

        for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
            sum+=getStoreValue(i);
        }
        return sum;


    }


}

private int getStoreValue(long index){
    int result = 0;

    if(!syraSumHashTable.containsKey(index)){
        syraSumHashTable.put(index, printSyra(index,1));
    }

    result = (Integer)syraSumHashTable.get(index);

     return result;

}

public static int printSyra(long num, int count) {
    if (num == 1) {
        return count;
    }
    if(num%2==0){

        return printSyra(num/2, ++count);
    }

    else{

        return printSyra((num*3)+1, ++count) ;

    }
}


}
```

Since I have to add to the sum of the previous numbers, I will end up Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space for a huge value of n. I know the hashtable is suppose to assist in speeding up the calculations. How do I make sure that my recursion method, printSyra can return the value early if it has encountered an element that I have calculated before using the HashMap.

Driver Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Test t1 = new Test();
    System.out.println(t1.lengths(90090249));

    //System.out.println(t1.lengths(3));
}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of `syraSumHashTable`?

Comment: I am suppose to use it to store the previous results of the calculations for printSyra(n) so that it can be more efficient.

Comment: And how do you think it helps you? You never call `getStoreValue()` with the same `index` argument twice - so you never really use cached values in `syraSumHashTable`...

Comment: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError - If you need to store huge sequence use database

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz: Yes, I realise I should have call it from my recursion method. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use iterative method instead of recursion. that recursive method will make pressure on the stack trace of the thread.

```
public static int printSyra(long num, int count) {
    if (num == 1) {
        return count;
    }

    while (true) {
            if (num == 1) break; else if (num%2 == 0) {num /= 2; count++;) else {num = (num*3) + 1; count++;} 
    }
    return count;
}
```